# Sorting List with Custom object by another List using IComparer

Tags: c#, .net, list, interface, icomparer

My question is about the `IComparer` interface, I never worked with it before, so I hope you can help me set up everything right.

I have to use the interface to sort an list of own objects by the exact sequence of another `List<int>`. 
I couldn't find anything usefull with that problem on the net, everything I found were linq statements, that I can not use.

Here is the example code:

```
public class What : IComparer<What>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Ever { get; set; }

    public What(int x_ID, string x_Ever)
    {
        ID = x_ID;
        Ever = x_Ever;
    }

    public int Compare(What x, What y)
    {
        return x.ID.CompareTo(y.ID);
    }
}
```

Some data to work with:

```
List<What> WhatList = new List<What>()
{
    new What(4, "there"),
    new What(7, "are"), 
    new What(2, "doing"),
    new What(12, "you"),
    new What(78, "Hey"),
    new What(63, "?")
};
```

And the list with the correct order:

```
List<int> OrderByList = new List<int>() { 78, 4, 63, 7, 12, 2 };
```

So now how can I tell `IComparer` to sort by the `OrderByList`? 
I really got no clue how to do that, I know this would be pretty easy with linq, but I don't have the opportunity to use it.

Comment: Out of interest, why no LINQ?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all the `ID` values will exist in your `OrderBylist` set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few tings wrong with your code as it currently stands. If you look at the [docs for `IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) you'll see that the `T` is what you're saying you are going to compare. In your code this is `Test` but you go on to code for comparisons of `What` - this means that your code will not compile. See [here](http://rextester.com/LLZWZ20401) - error message is:

> 'Rextester.What' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer.Compare(Rextester.Test, Rextester.Test)'
>   <sub>(Ignore the "Rextester" bit there!).</sub>

With all that said and done, you should implement a `WhatComparer`:

```
public class WhatComparer : IComparer<What>
{
    private List<int> orderBy;
    public WhatComparer(List<int> orderBy)
    {
        this.orderBy = orderBy;
    }

    public int Compare(What x, What y)
    {
        return orderBy.IndexOf(x.ID).CompareTo(orderBy.IndexOf(y.ID));
    }
}
```

And use that for ordering:

```
 WhatList.Sort(new WhatComparer(OrderByList));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/BZKO33641

Answer (score 3):

You should create another class to do the comparison, and give the desired order to that:

```
public class OrderComparer : IComparer<What>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, int> idIndexes = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    public OrderComparer(List<int> idOrders)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < idOrders.Length; i++)
        {
            idIndexes[idOrders[i].ID] = i;
        }
    }

    public int Compare(What x, What y)
    {
        return idOrders[x.ID].Compare(idOrders[y.ID]);
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
WhatList.Sort(new OrderComparer(OrderByList));
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use a custom [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx):

```
WhatList.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    return OrderByList.IndexOf(x.ID).CompareTo(orderByList.IndexOf(y.ID));
});
```